# Multiple file uploader in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

By default , magento have the file upload option under customise option->option type in product form.

How to add multiple file uploader under customise option .

Thanks.

Comment: Have you fix this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256615/upload-image-in-custom-option?