# Upload image in custom option

Tags: magento2.2, custom-options, php-7

I want to add the file uploaded in custom option (adminend).

**In CustomOption modifier:**

```
return [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('Image Uploader'),
                    'componentType' => 'fileUploader',
                    'formElement' => 'fileUploader',
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/file-uploader',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'Magento_Ui/components/file-uploader',
                    'dataScope' => 'file',
                    'fileInputName' => 'image',
                    'uploaderConfig' => [
                        'url' => $this->urlBuilder->addSessionParam()->getUrl(
                            'product/upload/image'
                        ),
                    ],

                    'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                ],
                [
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/thumbnail',
]
            ],
        ]
    ];
```

> In Image Controller

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
    }

    /**
     * Upload file controller action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $imageId = $this->_request->getParam(image);
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir($imageId);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
            ->setData($result);
    }
```

> In di.xml

```
<virtualType name="XXX\YYY\ImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
<arguments>
    <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">option/images</argument>
    <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">option</argument>
    <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
        <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
        <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="XXX\YYY\Controller\Adminhtml\Upload\Image">
<arguments>
    <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">XXX\YYY\ImageUpload</argument>
</arguments>
</type>
```

But not working..
It throws

> Invalid parameter given. A valid $_FILES[] identifier is expected.

Thanks

Comment: I have faced the following error  while saving - Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/m233/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3105

If you have any solution then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
      $imageId = $this->_request->getParam(image);
```

Need to use

```
         $files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();
```

Comment: it expect second parameter expect to be string but object given.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to below, It should work.

```
    // Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
    $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'yourFieldName']);
    $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf']);
    // Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory
    $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
    $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
    $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
    // Magento\Framework\Filesystem
    $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('customer');
    $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);

    $image = $result['yourFieldName'];
```